# Trying to make a visualization for training performance

Tags: scikit-learn, visualization, training, performance

I am using scikit learn's BayesianRidge model to fit a regression to tabular data of d features and N sample. I have already tested how well my model performs using a repeated kfold cross validation check on the dataset. However, when I do this, I cannot make a visualization of how this model performed because I use scikit learns cross_validate method which only returns an array of the testing scores.

This is not ideal for me because I want to know what the model has learned, which in my case is the weight vector, lambda and alpha parameters, and the covariance of the posterior over the weight vector. And I cannot extract this from the cross_validate method (to my knowledge) because I can't extract the fitted models per test.

I also had hoped to create a visualization of model performance. I know I get the scores of model performance from the cross_validate method, but a visualization would be preferable. So, I was thinking of training the model on the whole dataset, using scikit learn's BayesianRidge, then obtaining estimates for the labels using the .predict(X) method, where X = whole dataset. Then I could make a one-to-one plot of estimated labels versus observed labels

What I am wondering is (1) is there a way to extract the best model from scikit learn's cross_validate method. (2) If there is not, then is it valid to fit a model on the whole dataset then make predictions using the whole dataset to get a feeling for training performance? I only want to do this to get the learned parameters and a visualization.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Please try to give more detail about what you're doing because it's a bit unclear: what is the task, data? What kind of "one to one plot"? it's quite strange to care only about the training set perf in supervised learning, because by definition the training set is annotated so one can just store these labels and have perfect perf.

Comment: Hi, Erwan. I have updated my question, hope this clears things up a bit! If not just let me know

Comment: Thank you. I have the feeling that there's a bit of confusion: yes you can use CV for training several models and then extract the best, i.e. the one which obtains highest performance (used very often for parameter tuning). But in this case you should have another fresh test set on which you apply the selected model (see [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/93733/training-a-model-with-cross-validation)). you should not use predictions on the training set as if they are reliable, there's a high risk that their error is under-estimated.

Comment: Technically you could also use CV for getting predictions on the training data, but normally you shouldn't use the same CV loop for both tuning parameters and getting predictions. Anyway I can't do an answer because I'm not familiar with this method, sorry. Good luck!